# How to prove $f(z)=f(z_0)+f^{\prime}(z_0)(z-z_0)+\eta(z-z_0)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, complex-numbers, analyticity

How to show that if $f(z)$ is an analytical function in a region containing $z_0$ then $$f(z)=f(z_0)+f^{\prime}(z_0)(z-z_0)+\eta(z-z_0)$$ where $\eta\rightarrow 0$ when $z\rightarrow z_0$.

Comment: Like calculus approach.

Comment: If there would have been couple of more tags then the tagline would have become longer than the question itself ;) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here: if it is analytic, then
$$
\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}=f'(z_0).
$$

We can define $\eta=\eta(z)$ to make the equation
$$
f(z)=f(z_0)+f'(z_0)(z-z_0)+\eta\cdot (z-z_0)
$$
true.  The question, then, is why must $\eta\to 0$ as $z\to z_0$? Well, we can see that
$$
\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}-f'(z_0)=\eta;
$$
so, the limit above (defining the derivative) completes the problem.